# Validate and sanitize an associative array according to a predefined key structure

Tags: php, arrays, validation, filtering, sanitization

I like an array to follow a defined structure like this:

```
array (
  'id' => '',
  'name' => '',
  'quantity' => '',
)
```

This structure will ensure that all new input will align perfectly with this multidimensional array list:

```
array (
    array (
      'id' => 'GFKHF312',
      'name' => 'Item 1',
      'quantity' => 1
    ),
    array (
      'id' => 'YUKKU134',
      'name' => 'item 2',
      'quantity' => 5
    ),
    array (
      'id' => 'TRUT243',
      'name' => 'item 3',
      'quantity' => 10
    )
)
```

I would like a function which can determine the suitability of the input array and removed unneeded columns before it is pushed as a child of my master multidimensional array.

Example:

```
# When passed this data
array (
    'id' => 'GFKHF312',
    'name' => 'Item',
    'quantity' => 1,
    'new_key' => 120,
    'other_key' => 'fsdfs',
)

# It should filter to this data
array (
    'id' => 'GFKHF312',
    'name' => 'Item',
    'quantity' => 1
)
```

Second, if it doesn't have all the keys (`'id', 'name', 'quantity'`) defined in structure it should fail (return false or null).

Example:

```
# When passed this data
array (
    'id' => 'GFKHF312',
    'quantity' => 1,
)

# It should return this data
false
```

Is it possibly to use a PHP array function, like `array_diff()`, for that or are loops needed to accomplish this?

Comment: `array_filter` might be useful to look up in the good ol' docs :)

Comment: this isn't a multidimensional array, it's an array with empty strings

Comment: Wouldn't it make our lives easier if we had an example of input and desired output?

Comment: Thanks @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs but reading the docs is has not very clear if I could use this, so help to the rescue. I Also updated based in the feedback provided.

Answer (score 1):

I am generally opposed to mixing a return type of `array` with a return type of `boolean` -- it's valid, but I advise against it because PHP doesn't have convenient operators and functions for "falsible types", it does however have "nullable types".  As a compromise, I'll design my solution to unconditionally return a boolean type value and the input array will be modified by reference.

The core of what is required can be simply achieved using `array_diff_key()` to return `false` outcomes, and `array_intersect_key()` to prune unexpected columns from the array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/W6sRR))

```
function validateAndSanitize(array &$input, array $structure): bool {
    if (array_diff_key($structure, $input)) {
        return false; // missing required column(s)
    }
    $input = array_intersect_key($input, $structure); // prune unexpected columns
    return true;
}

$structure = ['id' => '', 'name' => '', 'quantity' => ''];

$array = [
    'id' => 'GFKHF312',
    'name' => 'Item',
    'quantity' => 1,
    'new_key' => 120,
    'other_key' => 'fsdfs',
];

if (!validateAndSanitize($array, $structure)) {
    echo "bonk\n";
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'id' => 'GFKHF312',
  'name' => 'Item',
  'quantity' => 1,
)
```